# How to access properties of Synthetic event in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For example, in the synthetic touchEvents:

`onTouchCancel onTouchEnd onTouchMove onTouchStart`

The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/events.html#touch-events) lists these properties:

```
boolean altKey
DOMTouchList changedTouches
boolean ctrlKey
boolean getModifierState(key)
boolean metaKey
boolean shiftKey
DOMTouchList targetTouches
DOMTouchList touches
```

How does one access these properties such as the `DOMTouchList targetTouches` strictly using javascript, NOT jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You access those properties of an event from the callback function you pass in to the event properties. For example:

`onTouchStart={event => { /* accessing metaKey */ console.log(event.metakey) }}`

Below is a live example. I am not using touchEvents as that only applies to mobile. I am accessing pageX property from onClick event.

```js
const Test = () => <div 
  style={{height: 200, width: 200, backgroundColor: 'red'}}
  onClick={e => console.log(e.pageX)}
/>

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
toggle(e) {
  console.log('e.ctrlKey', e.ctrlKey);
}
```

For targetTouches you could do something like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/targetTouches):

```
function touches_in_target(ev) {
  // Return true if all of the touches are within the target element;
  // otherwise return false.
  return (ev.touches.length == ev.targetTouches.length ? true : 
  false);
}
```

Comment: The function would then look something like `onTouchEventEnd{this.toggle}`?